# How can I send unknown Class type to method and generate a parameter for that class

Tags: java, android, class, oop, generics

I want to send a Java class to a method and receive it in arg that hold the same type of the class I sent, and every time I call this method I have a new class that I send to it.

Example:
this is the method in the class I created, and there is a type of generic T but this method I tried ain't working

```
<T> void getBedInfo(final RecyclerView MainRecycler, Class<T> adapterName){

    BedInfoGetter.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if(e!=null){
                return;
            }
            BedInfo.clear();
            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Bed oneBedInfo = documentSnapshot.toObject(Bed.class);
                activeValue = documentSnapshot.getId();
                oneBedInfo.getId(activeValue);
                BedInfo.add(oneBedInfo);
            }
            Adpter=new Adpter(BedInfo, context, activity);
            MainRecycler.setAdapter(AOP);
            MainRecycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        }
    });
}
```

this is the call of the method

```
databaseHandler.getBedInfo(MainRecycler, AdapterOnePatient.class);
```

Hope I explain the problem that I have
Thanks a lot!

Comment: for the second method you have to pass a class and not a string, something like "String.class"

Comment: @Boukharist Thanks for this note about the screenshots, I tried all the method as a string, as a class noting is working !!

Comment: why do you need "adaterName" for ?
it's unused in your code

Comment: So I can send the class that I want to generate, be aware every time I will send a different class type
once I will send like this 
`databaseHandler.getBedInfo(MainRecycler, **AdapterOnePatient.class**);`
the second time I will send the parameters like this 
`databaseHandler.getBedInfo(MainRecycler,**AdpterMainInterface.class**);`

I want every time I call the method to know what type of class I sent to it and generate type class of it
@Boukharist

Comment: @Boukharist if what I'm asking for work, I will replace the line with the new class I created 
`adapterName=new adapterName(BedInfo, context, activity);`

Comment: you have a problem with your conception, you need to make all your adapters extend from a BaseAdapter in order to construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do, is to create a BaseAdapter :

```
class BaseAdapter {
    BaseAdapter(BedInfo info, Context context, Activity activity) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then you need to modify your method to only accept generics extending your BaseAdapter :

```
<T extends BaseAdapter> void getBedInfo(final Recycler recycler, Class<T> adapterName) {

    BedInfoGetter.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                return;
            }
            BedInfo.clear();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Bed oneBedInfo = documentSnapshot.toObject(Bed.class);
                activeValue = documentSnapshot.getId();
                oneBedInfo.getId(activeValue);
                BedInfo.add(oneBedInfo);
            }
            T adapter = new BaseAdapter(info, context, activity);
            MainRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
            MainRecycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        }
    });
}
```

And the the third step is to use it like this :

```
getBedInfo(recycler, AdapterOnePatient.class);
```

Comment: So it's like creating polymorphism, it makes sense I will try it, Thanks, dude!